# Firebase Functions - Cannot read property inside a userID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have followed the docs and read [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js) example at the GitHub examples page but I still having a little issue that I'm not seeing it.

To put in context what I'm trying to do, I will explain below.

I have this database structure (sorry for the images and the code with some Spanish on it)

[image]

My goal is to trigger an event whenever a new `turno` is writed to the database, so lets say it's going to be `76,77,78..` and so on.

Now , I have my clients that sends to under `clientes - userID` the `notificar` numbers and the `device_token` is generated.

Now, I'm trying to fetch the value of each of those clients who match the value inside `turno`, so, if the value matches I send a push notification just to the `clientes` matching that same number.

But I'm having a problem at my Firebase functions console

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'notificar' of null
>       at databaseRoot.child.once.then (/user_code/index.js:23:51)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

This is the code I have made to trigger this behavior

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

//Uso el trigger onWrite, para ver cuando hay un nuevo turno, se ejecute toda esta funcion.
exports.sendClientesNotification = functions.database.ref('/farmacia/turno')
    .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {

        //Obtenemos el turno que va cambindo y lo guardamos en nuevoTurno
        const nuevoTurno = snapshot.after.val();
        console.log('Turno nuevo: '+nuevoTurno);


        const databaseRoot = snapshot.before.ref.root;
        return databaseRoot.child('/farmacia/clientes/{userID}').once('value').then((snapshot) =>{

    //Obtengo los valores de la referencia con el wildcard
            const getNumeroNotificar = snapshot.child('notificar').val();
            const getDeviceToken  = snapshot.child('device_token').val();
            console.log('Token: '+deviceToken+" Notificar: "+numeroNotificar);

           //Envio los valores a la promesa para luego mandar la notificacion
        return Promise.all([getNumeroNotificar, getDeviceToken]).then(results => {

            //Guardamos 
            const devicetoken = results[0];
            const numeroturnocliente = results[1];

            console.log('Nueva notificacion para '+devicetoken+' para el turno '+numeroturnocliente);

            if(numeroturnocliente === nuevoTurno){
             const payload = {
                    "data": {
                        "title": "Su turno ah llegado",
                        "body": "el turno "+numeroturnocliente+" es el siguiente a ser atendido.",
                        "icon": "ic_launcher",
                        "sound": "default",
                        "click_action": "delete_token"
              }
        };
                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(devicetoken,payload);
         }else{
             return 0;
    }



  });

        });


    });
```

I know the error is here

```
const getNumeroNotificar = snapshot.child('notificar').val();
```

and will also be in the line below it too, but I can't figure it out why is not fetching the value at that position. I have changed the reference and look the code up a couple of times. Since I'm in a learning process with javascript I usually got stuck with this kind of errors sometimes.

In simple words I'm trying to

1. Fetch turno wherever it changes (this is working right)
2. Fetch each user under clientes , get the notificar number (this is
   where I got stuck)
3. Compare each number and send the notification ( this is working
   right too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all children of a specific node and retrieving their values. So for your example, you can change it to something like this -

```js
  databaseRoot.child('/farmacia/clientes').once('value').then(snapshot => {
    const clientes = {}
    snapshot.forEach(data => {
      const key = data.key
      const value = data.val()
      //Do what you need, example-
      clientes[key] = value
    })
  })
```

Also, `getNumeroNotificar` `getDeviceToken` are not functions so you dont need to run them in a `Promise.all()`. `val()` is synchronous operation.

Comment: Thanks Badi, this is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that `userId` is undefined when you do

```
return databaseRoot.child('/farmacia/clientes/{userID}')...
```

Look at the example you refer to:

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/followers/{followedUid}/{followerUid}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
      .....
      const followedUid = context.params.followedUid;
      .....
      .....
      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
.ref(`/users/${followedUid}/notificationTokens`).once('value');
```

The last line uses **Template Literals**, a "new" feature of ES6, see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals and note the use of **back-ticks** (``) rather than the single quotes you are using.

Then, note how the `followedUid` constant is calculated from the `{followedUid}` placeholder that is in the path at which the function is triggered (with `context.params.followedUid;`).

In your case there is no `userID` placeholder in your path, nor any use of `context.params` to defined userId in your function, so at the end `'/farmacia/clientes/{userID}'` does not return the path you expect.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply , can you point me to some example in order to see how to fetch that userid ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén The problem is that by triggering the function when you write a new ’turno’ there is no way to identify a userId, with your data model. You should probably rework your data model in such a way you write under the desired userId node.

Comment: what kind of structure do you suggest? Because if I need to change the structure I will need to save turno inside each userID ?

Comment: You could save users by notificar number. Another approach is to use a query with equalTo, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data